# Why does this method of connecting and sending a SQL request not work but this other one does?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

The surprising part is that the one that doesn't work is from the [mssql package page](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mssql). Why is this one not working on my machine? What am I doing wrong here? The one that works is some example I found elsewhere online and it works great.

As a side note - do I need to asynchronously do these requests? The one that doesn't work uses `async`, when should I be using this?

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
const sql = require("mssql");

//Configuration for the database
const config = {
    user: 'sa',
    password: 'password',
    server: 'ipAddress', 
    database: 'DBName',
    trustServerCertificate: true, //Only setting this to true for testing on a local test server; Change to false when deploying to live
    encrypt: true,
};

app.get('/', function (req, res) {

    //THIS DOESNT WORK
     async () => {
         try {
          await sql.connect(config)
          var request = new sql.Request();
          const result = await request.query(`exec spTest null`)
          console.dir(result)
          res.send(result.recordset)
         } catch (err) {
          // ... error checks
          console.dir(err)
         }
     }

    //THIS ONE WORKS!
    // sql.connect(config, function (err) {
    
        // if (err) console.log(err);

        // // create Request object
        // var request = new sql.Request();
           
        // // query to the database and get the records
        // request.query('exec spTest null ', function (err, recordset) {
            
            // if (err) console.log(err)

            // // send records as a response
            // console.log(recordset)
            // res.send(recordset);
            
        // });
    // });
});

var server = app.listen(5000, function () {
    console.log('Server is running...');
});
```

The one that doesn't work makes localhost:5000 not load anything. However, the one that works successfully returns the results of the SP:

```
{"recordsets":[[{"SomeTimestamp":"2023-06-21T11:32:03.827Z","OtherField":""}]],"recordset":[{"SomeTimestamp":"2023-06-21T11:32:03.827Z","OtherField":""}],"output":{},"rowsAffected":[1,1]}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems the "non-working" code is defining `async` function within the request handler function and may not be "invoked" when requesting that route.

Try changing it to something like this

```
app.get('/', async (req, res) => {
     try {
      await sql.connect(config)
      var request = new sql.Request();
      const result = await request.query(`exec spTest null`)
      console.dir(result)
      res.send(result.recordset)
     } catch (err) {
      // ... error checks
      console.dir(err)
     }
 }
```